# How to achieve different titles for different views in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website on which users can upload artworks and I have a view which displays specifically selected artwork, for example, if a user visits `http://example.com/artwork/GreenGarden` he is presented with the artwork that has name `GreenGarden` and likewise if he visits `http://example.com/artwork/BlueSky` he is presented with the artwork that has name `BlueSky`.

Now I want to somehow insert the name of the artwork in the title of the rendered HTML page, but I'm not quite sure how to do that since the `<head></head>` is shared between all my pages thanks to the layout. Right now no matter which URL I visit, the title is always "My Website" because that is what I've hardcoded in the title. I'd need to somehow dynamically populate the title based on the image's name.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/normalize.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>

    @yield('content')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/javascript.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your master layout file add this section

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

then in your blade file in which you extends this this layout just create this section

```
@section('title')
    write your page title here
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complement to @sandy response which is the most flexible as you can pass html struct along:

- A shorter way if only text is needed to be passed

`@section('title', '<insert_text_here>')`

- Another option would be to pass a variable to the @layout

```
In view file
@extends('layout_name', ['title' => '<title_here>'])

In layout
{{ $title ?? null }} // handle the presence of $title however you like
```

Comment: passing a variable is the way to go +1

Comment: There's no such directive called `@layout` you probably mean `@extends`